# Pyhtonanywhere Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pythonanywhere

Please take a look to my problem

[https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/33115/[text]](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/33115/%5Btext%5D)

Problem : i cant use discord on selenium normally at pythonanywhere, its gives [this](https://ibb.co/XSyDQn2)       error(Connection Problems? Let us know)

I think : discord uses a different domain from discord.com which are'nt in the pythonanywhere whitelist.

Script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
import time



driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://discord.com/login")
print("waiting")
time.sleep(10)

komut = """function login(token) {
setInterval(() => {
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = 
`"${token}"`
}, 50);
setTimeout(() => {
location.reload();
}, 2500);
}

login('discord token here')"""


driver.execute_script(komut)
print("executed")
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("http://discord.com/channels/@me")
```

Comment: If you're correct (and you may be), then you can't use PythonAnywhere.  There are thousands of hosting companies you could use.

Comment: Have you tried `discord.gg`?

Comment: It looks like you are reaching Discord but it's not letting you in -- did you try to ask their support? They may be blocking certain IPs, for example.